# how to use AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX so that you don't see the reload refresh.

i want if i change the select button from 1 to 5 that you can see 5

live change and that i can use the 5 in a php variable.

i got this:

```
<script>
        $(document).on('change', '#hoeveelheid', function(e) {
            var j_Hoeveelheid = this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'do.php',
                data: {aantal : j_Hoeveelheid},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.test').html(data);
                }
            });
        }           
</script>
```

Now is my question what i need to set in the do.php file?
so that my script works without any refresh visible.

Comment: move your code inside `document.ready`

Comment: When posting with ajax, it will just post your data to the url, and whatever you're printing on that page (do.php), will be returned to the success function, like you're already having in (data).

Comment: `'#hoeveelheid'` what is it? can you post your markup too?

Comment: Thanx Djip, now i know what its doing!

Comment: @Jai #hoeveelheid is the id of the select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*what i need to set in the do.php file?*

At php file you are sending this object:

```
data: {aantal : j_Hoeveelheid},
```

so you need to get the key `aantal` at php end.

You can do this in your php file:

```
<?php 
   $aantal = $_POST['aantal'];
   echo $aantal . " is the posted value of dropdown.";
?>
```